# What is the reason of reverberations in the mind?

Tags: meditation

One usually finds it sometimes some song is constantly being played in the mind even against one's wish. My question set is as follows -

1. Without the engagements of ears, how can one listen/hear those sounds? It is similar to asking how without eyes one can see the dreams?
2. How one can stop the play of these sounds?
3. What is the reason of these reverberations, lastly?

How quality scriptures anwer these questions?

Comment: We keep talking something in our mind all the time, that one?

Comment: @KrishnaShweta that is a small instance of this problem.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I think it's attachment - - attachment of either pleasantness or unpleasantness.

Comment: Any idea about 1st one? @SwiftPushkar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72948/discussion-between-swiftpushkar-and-rajas).

Comment: What are quality scriptures?

Comment: @Rickross Loosely speaking - the scriptures deal with the questions.

Comment: This is  question on neurobiology and not Hinduism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## what-is-the-reason-of-reverberations-in-the-mind

I am providing the answer based on Patanjali Yog-Sutras. Here Patanjali is describing our mind in detail . Pantanjali is saying that thought waves constantly  arose  in our mind , our senses are constantly giving our mind information from outside world. Because senses are attached to outside material world. Some of these thought waves are pleasant as well as unpleasant .

So constant attachment to the outside world and to material desires is the basic reasons these -reverberations occurs in our mind.  Our  memory is also crucial  part in this process.

---

> योगश्चित्तवृत्तिनिरोधः ॥2॥
>
> yogaś-citta-vṛtti-nirodhaḥ ||2||
>
> Yoga is the control of thought-waves in the mind. [**Sutra 2**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-sutras-with-vedanta-commentaries/d/doc115475.html)
>
> When an event or object in the external world is recorded by the
>   senses, a thought-wave is raised in the mind. The ego-sense identifies
>   itself with this wave. If the thought-wave is pleasant, the ego-sense
>   feels, "I am happy"; if the wave is unpleasant, "I am unhappy."
>
> In order to become enlightened we must bring the thought-waves under
>   control, so that this false identification may cease. The Gita teaches
>   us that "Yoga is the breaking of contact with pain." There are also
>   minds which, though they possess a certain degree of energy, can only
>   dwell on what is pleasant; they shrink away from the disagreeable
>   aspects of life. But every mind, no matter what its present nature,
>   can ultimately be disciplined and transformed—can become, in
>   Patañjali’s phrase, "one-pointed" and fit to attain the state of
>   perfect yoga. Knowledge or perception is a thought-wave (vritti) in
>   the mind.

---

## What is the reason of these reverberations, lastly?

The reason Paatanjali is giving is our mind and nature of it . As thought waves constantly arose in our mind just like ripples these thought waves are the reasons of this reverberations , which arose because our attachment to the external world / desires ,and the sensory instructions constantly send by our organs i.e pancha Indriyas. And our Memory.

> वृत्ति सारूप्यमितरत्र ॥4॥
>
> vṛtti sārūpyam-itaratra ||4||
>
> At other times, when he is not in the state of yoga, man remains
>   identified with the thought-waves in the mind.
>
> So normally these thought waves or reverberations occurs constantly in
>   our mind , when not in yoga.
>
> ---
>
> वृत्तयः पञ्चतय्यः क्लिष्टाक्लिष्टाः ॥5॥
>
> vṛttayaḥ pañcatayyaḥ kliṣṭākliṣṭāḥ ||5||
>
> There are five kinds of thought-waves---some painful, others not
>   painful.
>
> The idea that we should ultimately have to overcome even
>   those thought-waves which are "good," "pure" and "truthful" may at
>   first seem shocking to a student who has been trained in the Western
>   approach to morality. But a little reflection will show him that this
>   must be so. The external world, even in its most beautiful appearances
>   and noblest manifestations, is still superficial and transient. It is
>   not the basic Reality. We must look through it, not at it, in order to
>   see the Atman. [**Sutra 4 -5**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-sutras-with-vedanta-commentaries/d/doc115476.html)

---

**See the involvement  of memory function in occurance of reverberations in our mind in below sutra.**

> अनुभूतविषयासंप्रमोषः स्मृतिः ॥११॥
>
> anu-bhūta-viṣaya-asaṃpramoṣaḥ smṛtiḥ ||11||
>
> **Memory is when perceived objects are not forgotten, but come back to
>   consciousness.** Memory is a kind of secondary thought-wave. A wave of
>   direct perception causes a smaller ripple or series of ripples
>   [**Sutra 11**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-sutras-with-vedanta-commentaries/d/doc115477.html)

---

## How one can stop the play of these sounds?

In the [**sutra 15**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-sutras-with-vedanta-commentaries/d/doc115478.html) Patanjalii is giving us the advice about how to control the reverberations or thought wave arising in our mind  through Non-attachment.

> दृष्टानुश्रविकविषयवितृष्णस्य वशीकारसंज्णा वैराग्यम् ॥१५॥
>
> dṛṣṭa-anuśravika-viṣaya-vitṛṣṇasya vaśīkāra-saṃjṇā vairāgyam ||15||
>
> **Non-attachment** is self-mastery; it is freedom from desire for what is seen or heard.
>
> Also Patanjali in above sutra is saying that, " realizing that  thought
>   waves created in our mind  from  information send by our sense organs is not reality
>   but superficial and transient" , is another way to stop these sounds or
>   reverberations. And **yoga is the way to do this**.